# Android Admob Query - Lunar Lander

Tags: android, admob

I used to use processing from the old Lunar Lander example to display ads with Admob in Android apps.  However now when I try, I get the problem "The method onReceiveInterstitial(InterstitialAd) of type LunarLander must override a superclass method" on the following code:

```
@Override
public void onReceiveInterstitial(InterstitialAd interstitialAd) {
  if(interstitialAd == mInterstitialAd) {
    mInterstitialAd.show(this);
  }
}
```

I still have the problem if I remove the @override.  The activity is defined as 
public class LunarLander extends Activity implements AdListener, InterstitialAdListener

Has anyone else experienced this? I used to be able to get this to complile, but it won't since I reloaded eclipse.   Thanks in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 1):

This is likely using an old old version of the AdMob SDK before the Google AdMob SDK rewrite.  The Google AdMob SDK doesn't have an InterstitialAdListener in it's API.

I'd recommend [downloading](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/download) the latest Google AdMob SDK and checking out the official [documentation](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/android/fundamentals) on how to get started.